# NW102 Pleaxgear nettwork adapter driver error

Tags: networking, drivers

I have bought NW102 PLEXGEAR wifi adapter. I get following error when trying to run the install.sh downloaded from homepage.

I get following error message

```
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=aarch64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-1104-raspi/build M=/home/torehaav/Desktop/594290_61346-driver---manual/Driver/linux/driver/rtl8821AU_linux_v4.3.14_13455.20150212_BTCOEX20150128-51  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1104-raspi'
Makefile:705: arch/aarch64/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/aarch64/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1104-raspi'
make: *** [Makefile:1551: modules] Error 2    
##################################################

Compile make driver error: 2

Please check error Mesg

##################################################
```

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Have a nice day